# How can I change the default color scheme?

Tags: windows-xp, color-theme

Is there a way to set the default blue Windows XP color scheme to black or grey?

Comment: You can change the current theme using the Display Control Panel. There's built-in a Silver one that is greyish and you can customize it or create your own by tweaking the settings under the other tabs. OS supplied .theme files are stored in the \Windows\Resources folder if you select the Browse option on the Theme pull-down menu.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change to one of Windows XP's built in alternative color schemes (silver or olive green):

1. Right click any blank spot on your Desktop and select `Properties`.
2. Select the `Appearance` tab, and click the drop-down arrow labeled `Color scheme:`.
3. Choose a scheme and click "OK". The scheme is now changed.

You can also [download different color schemes from the internet](http://customize.org/xpthemes) and use [this tutorial](http://customize.org/xpthemes/help/How_To_Use_Xp_Themes) for installation instructions. There are lots of different color schemes available so I'm sure one of them will be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to a grey theme is the vanilla silver theme available on windows. It still has that green start button

Assuming you want a black version of the Luna Theme, you'd want to look for the zune theme [direct link off microsoft](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=75078) (black with orange button)

[image]

Royale Noir would be another option - its a little unfinished, but its a nicer theme IMO. I've seen it on [istartedsomething](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20061029/royale-noir/) and was my default theme for quite a while.

[image]

While it isn't a black theme, i use the xp embedded theme i snarfed off the internet somewhere. Its fairly professional looking and pretty easy on the eyes

[image] - [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Windows_XP_Embedded.png)

All these are official themes and none of these needs a uxtheme patch and would work perfectly on a windows xp system with no changes.

If you don't mind patching uxtheme, grab [royale noir remixed](http://oddbasket.deviantart.com/art/Royale-Remixed-44294818), which is a finished up version of royale noir.